# ContentNegotiatingViewResolver not showing up in Spring Boot --debug auto configuration report

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Trying to understand Spring Boot a bit more closely, I created a new project using STS starter wizard with MVC selected. The `pom.xml` generated by STS wizard has this, which looks correct to my eyes:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As per [Spring Boot Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration), I should be getting a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` autoconfigured. But I don't find it in my [Auto-Configuration report](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sanjay-public/spring-boot-web-auto-configuration-report.txt). Was curious to know where I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: It is there, it is the bean named `viewResolver`.

Comment: Make that an answer Marten?